# How do I get an image to be displayed when I "Publish to Web" via Google Sheets?

Tags: html, google-sheets

This is the link I've published [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSe_LJGhWHX-I_Z7345j0W2p-tza_KEDgf7EwiDYd5ta9aJTVbP8N0hxj7gHGR8jtt5sdfg7M9rqI8-/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true)

What other people are seeing:

[image]

What they should be seeing:

[image]

- As you can see from the first pic Error is 403 permission denied.
- I've checked permissions on google drive for the folder and the file itself, and both are set to public.
- I've tried inserting the picture with the "Get shareable link" in to the document but that is unable to be inserted.
- I've tried inserting the pic via a different public http address but still the same permission issue when published on the google sheet.

What am I missing?

And yes, there will be only one pic when I get this sorted :)

Comment: Are you getting any error codes in the console window?

Comment: @StrayAnt The only error I see in the console is:

This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”.

Comment: Make sure your current IP is included in the Access Control List (ACL).

Comment: Where is ACL implemented in google apps? Also this a private account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- Your images are put as "Image in cell" and "Image over cells".
- Your Spreadsheet is published to the Web.
- You want to show those images on the web published Spreadsheet by accessing with the browser.

#### Issue and workaround:

In this case, when you login to Google account as the owner of the Spreadsheet, you can see those images on the web published Spreadsheet by accessing with your browser. Unfortunately, other users cannot see them. I think that this might be the current specification at Google side. So, in order to make images show to other users, how about the following workaround?

#### Workaround 1:

Share the Spreadsheet with the users. By this, when the user logs in own Google account, the user can see the images. But, in this case, the users that the Spreadsheet is not shared with cannot see them.

#### Workaround 2:

When you want to show the images to the users who are without logging in each Google account, it is required to share publicly the Google Spreadsheet as "Viewer" of "Anyone with the link". By this, the users can see the images for both with and without logging in Google account..

#### Note:

- When the image is put with `=IMAGE(URL)`, all users can see the images on the web published Spreadsheet without logging in Google account and sharing publicly.

Comment: Yep, looks like W2 will be the way. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Cenzo Thank you for replying.